# how to open google play music app with a search query using javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a voice bot made from javascript. Is there is any possible way to start playing a respective song or search for the song in play music app from the browser ?

Comment: You can select music from files and set music filter to the files which user can select.

Comment: Thank you for replying sir. But all I need is to open the play music app having search results from the browser itself.